# Remove seconds from time field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do I remove seconds and only show `hh:mm`?

The field type is `time`. Eg:

```
SELECT opentime, closetime FROM hours

Result:
17:00:00  |  23:00:00
17:30:00  |  23:40:00
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT
  TIME_FORMAT(opentime, "%H:%i") as opentime,
  TIME_FORMAT(closetime, "%H:%i") as closetime
FROM hours;
```